# Sending 0x04 - like hexadecimal char[] data using DatagramPacket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a `DatagramSocket` and want to send `char[] charData = { 0xff, 0x04, 0x02, 0xfb}` data via `DatagramSocket` using `DatagramPacket`.

DatagramPacket is using `byte[]` as data. But I should send it like `charData` variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Beware that java char is 2 Byte not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the case. I simply do `"ff0402fb".getbytes` and its working.

Answer (score 0):

you could use ObjectOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(charData);

byte[] toSend = baos.toByteArray();
oos.close();
baos.close();
int port = xxxx;
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(toSend,toSend.length,InetAddress.getByName("host"),port);
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
s.send(p);
```

Comment: @CodersParadise Martze already gave you a big hint: you are putting a **byte** sequence into a **char** array. Chars have a size of 2 bytes in Java. So effectively you are sending the following byte sequence: *0, 0xff, 0, 0x04, 0, 0x02, 0, 0xfb*. If you have to make use of that char array, then you can try rewriting that sequence as: *0xff04, 0x02fb* (but I'm not sure whether that will work). Or just use a byte array instead. Obviously you are not required to use a char array in the first place!

Comment: @NobuGames thank you for your response. Its not a must to use char array. But I dont know how to implement hexadecimal in a byte array. Thats why i have written it in C way. Can you please tell me byte array version of *{0xff, 0x04, 0x02, 0xfb}*

Comment: @CodersParadise The problem I see here is a possible mess up with endianness. As far as I know the Java VM operates based on big endian (high byte first). If your server expects little endian you need to take that into account and swap the byte order accordingly. The byte array version looks as follows: byte[] data = {0xff, 0x04, 0x02, 0xfb};. Swapped to little endian can look like as follows: byte[] data = {0xfb, 0x02, 0x04, 0xff}; (one word / dword) or alternatively: byte[] data = {0x04, 0xff, 0xfb, 0x02}; (two words)

Comment: Oh. I remember that byte[] data = {0x04, 0xff, 0xfb, 0x02}; is not acceptable for java, i have already tried that one.

Comment: @CodersParadise Oops sorry, I didn't check it. You need to be careful that Java's numerical literals can be interpreted to be of a specific primitive type. In case of the hex value 0xff the compiler interprets it as an int. Java does not automatically cast numeric types to anything with less precision because of the risk of losing information. A Java byte is defined to range from -128 to 127, so 0xff for example is out of range. You have to explicitly cast these values to bytes: byte[] data = {0x04, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xfb, 0x02};

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I simply do **"ff0402fb".getbytes** and its working.